# Order my SQL database using the following criteria:

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a data base, in this SQL db I have ideas, in different communities (English and Spanish). When you are the English version of my site you see all ideas in English. When you are in the Spanish version you see ideas in Spanish. Ok, but my probleme is that when for example 10 consecutive ideas in Spanish are registered in the db , the English version become very slow.

In the data base is ok if I have 10 consecutive ideas in Spanish.

My question is:

How can I (using PHP and SQL) order the ideas in the db like this: one in Spanish, one in English, one in Spanish, one in English, one in Spanish, one in English??

Comment: I'm not really sure why you would want to do it? Don't you just want to retrieve the data based on the community?

Comment: 1. don't mix mysql and sql-server - they are different. 2. give us code how you get current ideas, what db structure, and how do you output them?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go back and rewrite your question so that it's easier to understand.  From what I can tell, you want to filter on your communities field. So...

```
Select * from ideas where communities = 'english';
```

For speed reasons, I would create an index on communities to make indexing faster

If you're talking about inserting 'ideas' into your database by alternating between spanish and english for testing purposes, then create a for loop in php and use modulus division to determine if the iteration is even or odd.

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){
    if($i % 2 == 0){
        //the loop is even, so insert a spanish idea
    }else{
        //the loop is odd, so insert an english idea
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry it was a bad question, i solve my problem.

this was the solution

```
WHERE community='english'
```

it work better now.